# How to dynamically determine if an object's value contains a character?

Tags: javascript, arrays, object

There is an array of objects:

I need to check if an object's value contains "$", then remove it

I have tried:

```js
var arr = [
    {
        "Account ID": 329,
        "Avg Opportunity Days": 690,
        "Avg Revenue": "$11888801",
        "Create Date": 41648,
        "Factored Revenue": "$1188880",
        "FactoredProductRevenue": "$1188880",
        "Month": "Nov",
        "Month_Number": 11,
        "Opportunity Count": 1,
        "Opportunity Days": 690,
        "Opportunity ID": 428,
        "Opportunity Revenue": "$11888801",
        "Partner ID": 90,
        "Product ID": 2,
        "ProductRevenue": "$11888801",
        "Sales Stage ID": 1,
        "Tot Opportunity Days": 690,
        "Year": 2015

    },
    {
        "Account ID": 194,
        "Avg Opportunity Days": 396,
        "Avg Revenue": "$11706144",
        "Create Date": 41821,
        "Factored Revenue": "$1170614",
        "FactoredProductRevenue": "$1170614",
        "Month": "Aug",
        "Month_Number": 8,
        "Opportunity Count": 1,
        "Opportunity Days": 396,
        "Opportunity ID": 289,
        "Opportunity Revenue": "$11706144",
        "Partner ID": 8,
        "Product ID": 17,
        "ProductRevenue": "$11706144",
        "Sales Stage ID": 1,
        "Tot Opportunity Days": 396,
        "Year": 2015
    }
]

        arr.forEach(function(obj) {
            Object.values(obj).forEach(function(ele) {
                if (ele.indexOf('$') > -1) {
                    ele = ele.replace('$','');
                }
            });
        })
```

but it returns Uncaught TypeError: ele.indexOf is not a function

The object can be another, the important thing is $

Comment: You're iterating through all the values of the object, some of which are Numbers which don't have an `.indexOf()` method. You'll need to first check if the value is a String.

Comment: Well, a number does not have an `indexOf` method, so that's probably what's causing the error... Maybe check the `typeof` the value before calling methods on it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code fails because some of your values are not strings, and don't have `indexOf` method. Check if the value is a string, and if its, check if it includes the `$` sign (or use `indexOf`).

In addition, you can't assign directly to the value (`ele`). Use `Object.entries()` instead of `Object.value()` to get the keys as well, and assign the new value to `obj[key]`.

```js
const arr = [{"Account ID":329,"Avg Opportunity Days":690,"Avg Revenue":"$11888801","Create Date":41648,"Factored Revenue":"$1188880","FactoredProductRevenue":"$1188880","Month":"Nov","Month_Number":11,"Opportunity Count":1,"Opportunity Days":690,"Opportunity ID":428,"Opportunity Revenue":"$11888801","Partner ID":90,"Product ID":2,"ProductRevenue":"$11888801","Sales Stage ID":1,"Tot Opportunity Days":690,"Year":2015},{"Account ID":194,"Avg Opportunity Days":396,"Avg Revenue":"$11706144","Create Date":41821,"Factored Revenue":"$1170614","FactoredProductRevenue":"$1170614","Month":"Aug","Month_Number":8,"Opportunity Count":1,"Opportunity Days":396,"Opportunity ID":289,"Opportunity Revenue":"$11706144","Partner ID":8,"Product ID":17,"ProductRevenue":"$11706144","Sales Stage ID":1,"Tot Opportunity Days":396,"Year":2015}]

arr.forEach(obj => {
  Object.entries(obj).forEach(([key, value]) => {
    if (typeof value === 'string' && value.includes('$')) {
      obj[key] = value.replace('$', '');
    }
  });
})

console.log(arr)
```

Answer (score 1):

you're getting that error because some `values` are not strings and thus don't have the `.indexOf()` method. And even if you had proper checks for that, you're not affecting the original object in any way.

Here's a solution to change the object in place:

```js
arr.forEach(function (obj) {
  Object.entries(obj).forEach(function ([key, val]) {
    if (typeof val == "string" && val.indexOf("$") > -1) {
      obj[key] = val.replace(/\$/g, "");
    }
  });
});
```